# ¿Cómo puedo adjuntar archivo en PHP?

Tags: php

Estuve realizando sistema, donde el siguiente campo es contacto, en que el usuario envié información como por ejemplo: su nombre, email, telefono, cargo y un campo de mensaje. Pero ahora estoy agregando el campo adjuntar archivo en el que el usuario pueda enviar archivos y que me los haga llegar a mi correo. El problema es saber cual es mi error en mi código PHP o que falta agregar para el envió de archivo adjunto. Las pruebas lo realizo desde un servidor.

Este es mi código en PHP:

```
<?php

    //Variables para los campos de texto
    $nombre = strip_tags($_POST["nombre"]);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST["email"]);
    $cargo = strip_tags($_POST["cargo"]);
    $telefono = strip_tags($_POST["telefono"]);
    $mensaje = strip_tags($_POST["mensaje"]);

    //Variables para los datos del archivo
    $nameFile = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $sizeFile = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $typeFile = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

    $fecha = time();
    $fechaFormato = date('d/m/y', $fecha);

    $corredoDestino = 'prueba@gmail.com';

    //asunto del correo
    $titulo = "Mensaje de la web recibido";

    // -> mensaje en formato Multipart MIME
    $cabecera = "MIME-VERSION: 1.0\r\n";
    $cabecera .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;";
    $cabecera .= "boundary=\"=C=T=E=C=\"\r\n";
    $cabecera .= "From: {$mail}";

    //Primera parte del cuerpo del mensaje
    $cuerpo = "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-type: text/plain";
    $cuerpo .= "charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; //línea vacía
    $cuerpo .= "Haz recibido un mensaje atravez de la página solmit.net \r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Mensaje enviado por: " .$nombre. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "ponerse en contacto con: " .$email. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Selecciono el cargo de: " .$cargo. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "El teléfono de la persona es: " .$telefono. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Mensaje: " .$mensaje. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= " Enviado el: " .$fechaFormato. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";

    // -> Segunda parte del mensaje (archivo adjunto)
        // -> encabezado de la parte
    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
    $cuerpo .= "name=" .$nameFile. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
    $cuerpo .= "filename= " .$nameFile. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; //línea vacía

    $fp = fopen($tempFile, "rb");
    $file = fread($fp, $sizeFile);
    $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

    $cuerpo .= "$file\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; //linea vacia
    //Delimitador de final del mensaje.
    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=--\r\n";

    //Enviar el correo
    $envio = mail($corredoDestino, $titulo, $cuerpo, $cabecera);

    if($envio) {
        header('Location: index.html');
    } else {
        echo "Error de envío";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `mail` de PHP no es de las mejores.

Ellos mismos [dicen](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) algo como esto:

> **Nota:** Si la intención es enviar HTML u otro tipo de correo complejo, es recomendable usar el paquete PEAR » PEAR::Mail_Mime.

Entre lo que ellos llaman *correo complejo*, se encuentra precisamente el envío de archivos adjuntos.

Existe una librería llamada **[PHPMailer (ver documentación)](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial)** que es sin duda la mejor en su género y te facilitará de una manera sorprendente el envío de mensajes de todo tipo.

Por ejemplo, para enviar adjuntos:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('myfriend@example.net', 'My Friend');
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
$mail->addAttachment($path, $name, $encoding, $type);

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

En la doc explican otras maneras posibles de adjuntar archivos.