# ¿Usar mail() de php incrustando un archivo?

Tags: php

```
   $to = $email;
    $subject = "Pedido #".$id_factura;

    //se puede hacer esto porque el mail se manda pero no sale este 
     //archivo

   $message = file_get_contents('../prueba.html',true);

  $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ventas@homocervecerus.com";


   mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

o como puedo hacer para mandar un mail que vaya con otro archivo

Comment: Enviar archivos con `mail()` es una tarea no recomendada por PHP mismo. Esta nota viene en el Manual de PHP: *Si la intención es enviar HTML u otro tipo de correo complejo, es recomendable usar el paquete PEAR » PEAR::Mail_Mime.* Doy [más detalles aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116554/29967). La opción mejor sería PHPMailer. (Ver enlaces en la otra respuesta).

Answer (score 1):

Le recomiendo utilizar la librería PHPMailer, de esta manera podrá realizar el envio de correos de una manera mas sencilla, la pagina oficial es la siguiente: http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Utilizando esta librería, puede adjuntar un archivo a través de una linea:

```
$email->AddAttachment();
```

El ejemplo completo seria el siguiente:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'micorreo@ejemplo.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Mi Nombre';
$email->Subject   = 'Asunto';
$email->Body      = $textoDelMensaje;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinatario@ejemplo.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'RUTA_DEL_ARCHIVO_AQUI';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'Archivo.pdf' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Luego tenemos que iniciar la validación por SMTP:
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = ""; // A RELLENAR. Aquí pondremos el SMTP a utilizar. Por ej. mail.midominio.com
$mail->Username = ""; // A RELLENAR. Email de la cuenta de correo. ej.info@midominio.com La cuenta de correo debe ser creada previamente. 
$mail->Password = ""; // A RELLENAR. Aqui pondremos la contraseña de la cuenta de correo
$mail->Port = 465; // Puerto de conexión al servidor de envio. 
$mail->From = ""; // A RELLENARDesde donde enviamos (Para mostrar). Puede ser el mismo que el email creado previamente.
$mail->FromName = ""; //A RELLENAR Nombre a mostrar del remitente. 
$mail->AddAddress("correo"); // Esta es la dirección a donde enviamos 
$mail->IsHTML(true); // El correo se envía como HTML 
$mail->Subject = “Titulo”; // Este es el titulo del email. 
$body = “Hola mundo. Esta es la primer línea ”; 
$body .= “Aquí continuamos el mensaje”; $mail->Body = $body; // Mensaje a enviar. $exito = $mail->Send(); // Envía el correo.
if($exito){ echo ‘El correo fue enviado correctamente.’; }else{ echo ‘Hubo un problema. Contacta a un administrador.’; }
```

Usa PHPMailer tiene funciones como :

- Envíos a varios remitentes, con CC, CCO, etc.
- Soporta 8bits, base64 y binarios
- Autenticación por SMTP en puertos 25 sin encriptar, 587 TLS, 465 SSL
- Envíos con HTML
- Envíos de emails con adjuntos
- Inclusión de imágenes en el correo, etc

Existen más posibilidades a agregar como fichero adjuntos y copias ocultas. Consulta el manual oficial aquí en su libreria [git](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)