# Error al enviar correo con archivo adjunto usando función mail PHP

Tags: php

Saludos, estoy enviando un correo con archivo adjunto usando php con la función mail de php, pero me esta dando problemas al realizar el envió, dice que fallo el envió, y no encuentro el error. este es mi codigo:

```
<?php  
session_start();
include 'conexion.php';

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

    if(!empty($_FILES['archivo']['name'])){
        $names = $_SESSION['usuario']['nombres'];
        $ape = $_SESSION['usuario']['apellidos'];
        $dni = $_SESSION['usuario']['dni'];
        $tlf1 = $_SESSION['usuario']['fijo'];
        $tlf2 = $_SESSION['usuario']['mov'];
        $email = $_SESSION['usuario']['email'];
        $d_entrega = $_SESSION['usuario']['direccion_entrega'];
        $d_facturacion = $_SESSION['usuario']['direccion_facturacion'];
        $cod = $_POST['cod'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        $temp_name = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];

        $base = basename($file_name);
        $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

        $extensiones = array(".doc",".docx",".pdf",".png",".jpg",".jpeg");

        if(in_array($extension,$extensiones)){
            $from = $_POST['email'];
            $to = "hmla9612@gmail.com";
            $asunto = "CONFIRMACIÓN DE PAGO DE PEDIDO";

            $mensaje = '
            <html>
                <body>
                    <p><img src="http://mvmultiservicios.es/banners/multi_mv_.jpg" width="669" height="348" /><br />
                      <br />
                    </p>
                    <h2 class="tre2">DATOS DE LA PERSONA QUIEN CONFIRMO SU DEPOSITO O TRANSFERENCIA<br />
                    </h2>
                    <h4>Nombres: '.$names.' '.$ape.'</h4>
                    <h4>DNI: '.$dni.'</h4> <br />
                    <h4>Telefono Fijo: '.$tlf1.'</h4>
                    <h4>Telefono Movil: '.$tlf2.'</h4>
                    <h4>Email: '.$email.'</h4>
                    <h4>Dirección de entrega: '.$d_entrega.'</h4>
                    <h4>Dirección de Facturación: '.$d_facturacion.'</h4>
                    <br><br>
                    <h4>'.$cod.'</h4>
                    <img src="http://mvmultiservicios.es/images/abajoemail.jpg" width="669" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
                    <map name="Map" id="Map">
                      <area shape="rect" coords="37,227,113,250" href="http://mvmultiservicios.es/contacto.php" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="12,5,656,40" href="http://mvmultiservicios.es/reporte.php" target="_blank" />
                    </map>
                    <br />
                    <span class="trebww"> Multiservicios Melga-Villafuerte SL.<br />
                    Dirección: C/Padilla 334-336, Local 1, C.P. 08025 Barcelona<br />
                    +34931 75 69 73 +34 601 020 475<br />
                    info@mvmultiservicios.es  | comercial@mvmultiservicios.es</span></h3>
                    <h2 class="tre2">&nbsp; </h2>
                    <h2 class="treb">&nbsp; </h2>
                    <p>  <br />
                      <br />
                    </p>
                </body> 
            </html>
        ';

        $file = $temp_name;
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

        $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
        $header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--" .$uid. "\r\n";
        $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

        $header .= "--".$ui."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

            if(mail($to, $asunto, $mensaje, $header)){
                echo "success";
            }else{
                echo "fallo el envio";
            }

        }else{
            echo "El formato del archivo no es admitido";
        }
    }else{
        echo "No hay archivo adjuntado";
    }
}
?>
```

Como dije lo que me imprime es echo "fallo el envió". No he podido encontrar la solución

Comment: No te muestra ningun error?

Comment: Solo me ejecuta el echo "Fallo el envio" sin ningun tipo de error. No se si haya una forma de que me muestre que error hay. Se ejecuta es el else que esta en donde ejecuto la funcion mail()

Comment: agrega: error_reporting(-1); e ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); arriba de todo y ejecuta de nuevo a ver si te tira algun error referido al envio de mail

Comment: He activado los errores en mi cpanel y me arrojo esto: Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /home/boanerges/public_html/mvmultiservicios.es/tienda/confirm_import.php on line 85

Comment: Alejo, el mismo Manual dice que `mail` es una función para usos básicos, y que cuando se requiere un uso más avanzado es mejor pasar al uso de una librería. Yo te recomendaría `PHPMailer`. Ya traté de explicar lo mismo [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116554/29967), poniendo lo que he sacado del mismo Manual de PHP. Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes probar si lo siguiente a ver si te funciona:

Deberias cambiar la parte en la que armas el header y como llamas a la funcion mail por lo siguiente:

```
$header = "From: <".$from.">".PHP_EOL;
$header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL;
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"";

$message = "--" .$uid.PHP_EOL;
$message .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'.PHP_EOL;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$message .= $mensaje.PHP_EOL;
$message .= "--".$uid.PHP_EOL;
$message .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"".PHP_EOL;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".PHP_EOL;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$message .= $content.PHP_EOL;
$message .= "--".$uid."--";
```

Y llamas a la funcion mail asi:

```
mail($to, $asunto, $message, $header)
```

Por lo tanto separas el header del contenido de mensaje de esta manera a ver si te funciona.

Comment: Exactamente es eso lo que he hecho Leonardo. Me ha funcionado bien.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido! Saludos!