# ¿Cómo enviar un correo con archivo anexo en php?

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla, en la tabla tengo para descargar un archivo pdf y también el botón para enviar un correo. Lo que quiero hacer es que este archivo pdf se envíe anexo en el correo, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, estoy trabajando con la función de php

Esta es la vista:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">ORDENES DE COMPRA ACTIVAS</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
   <!-- /.row -->
   <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            ORDENES DE COMPRA
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="dataTables-example_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer">
                            <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="dataTables-example" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTables-example_info">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <th  rowspan="1" colspan="1">CONSECUTIVO</th>
                                        <th  rowspan="1" colspan="1">CODIGO OBRA</th>
                                        <th  rowspan="1" colspan="1">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                                        <th  rowspan="1" colspan="1">SOLICITADO POR</th>
                                        <th  rowspan="1" colspan="1">FECHA</th>
                                        <th  rowspan="1" colspan="1">ACCIONES</th>


                                          </th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                    foreach ($producto as $productos){
                                        echo '<tr class="gradeA odd" role="row" style="text-align: center;">
                                                <td>'.$productos['consecutivo'].'</td>
                                                <td>'.$productos['obra'].'</td>
                                                <td>'.$productos['des_re'].'</td>
                                                <td>'.$productos['encargado'].'</td>
                                                <td>'.$productos['fecha_requi'].'</td>


                                                <td>

                                            <a href="index.php?modulo=Requisicion2&controlador=requisicion2&funcion=getEditar&conse='.$productos['consecutivo'].'"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-md"><i class="fa fa  fa-pencil      "></i></button></a>
                                            <a href="index.php?modulo=Requisicion2&controlador=requisicion2&funcion=getConsultarpdf&consecutivo='.$productos['consecutivo'].'"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-md"><i class="fa fa fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></button></a>
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">


                                                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn- btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                                            <i class="fa fa  fa-paper-plane    "></i>
                                                        </button>';
                                    ?>
                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <form role="form" name="requisicion" method="post" action="<?php echo getUrl("Requisicion2","requisicion2","ordenEnvioCorreo"); ?>">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">CORREOS ELECTRONICOS </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>SELECCIONE EL DESTINATARIO:</label><br><BR>

                                                <label>Edilson Rivera</label><BR>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="correo1" value="xxxxx@gmail.com">xxxxxx@gmail.com
                                                    </label>
                                                </div><BR><BR>

                                                <label>Nelson Arango</label><BR>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="correo2" value="xxxxx@gmail.com">xxxxx@gmail.com
                                                    </label>
                                                </div><BR><BR>

                                                 <label>Coinsas</label><BR>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="correo3" value="xxxxxx@gmail.com">xxxxxx@gmail.com
                                                    </label>
                                                </div><BR><BR>

                                                 <label>Wisner Martinez</label><BR>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="correo4" value="xxxxxx@gmail.com">xxxxxxx@gmail.com
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- .panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>

                                                </td>


                                             </tr>

                                            <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>


                                    </tbody>

                            </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Y esta es la función:

```
function ordenEnvioCorreo(){
        $titulo = 'Orden de compra';
       $mail = 'Cuerpo orden de compra';
       $headers = "From:xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
       for ($i=1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
           if (isset($_POST['correo'.$i])) {
               $bool = mail('xxxxx@gmail.com, xxxxx@gmail.com,xxxxx@gmail.com, xxxxx@gmail.com', $titulo, $mail, $headers);
           }
       }

   }
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow.  La función `mail` de PHP es para envíos muy básicos de mensajes simples. Ellos mismos reconocen en el Manual que esa función no sirve para enviar adjuntos y recomiendan el uso de otras librerías. [Ya lo he explicado con más detalle en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116554/29967) a una pregunta idéntica a la tuya.

Comment: @A.Cedano, he estado buscando en internet y he encontrado que hay usuarios que han enviado archivos adjuntos con esa función, seguro es una más avanzada o no sé, pero he encontrado varios que han podido ejecutarlo con esta función.

Comment: María la verdad que nunca lo he probado, ahora reviso y te comento el resultado.

Comment: María en efecto, poder se podría, pero es super complicado manejar la cuestión de los encabezados, los mime type etc,que varían según el tipo de archivo a adjuntar. Convendría una biblioteca que hiciera eso de una forma transparente... [Mira esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12301358/5587982). En la respuesta aceptada te dicen lo mismo que te he dicho yo, y hay otra respuesta que muestra una manera de hacerlo con `mail` la cual parece funcionar. Sin embargo, observa la *verbosidad*  de ese código y todas las vueltas que debe dar para adjuntar un archivo...

Comment: ... imagina que tienes que enviar un email con varios tipos de archivo: `.jpg, .txt, .pdf, .doc, ...`  parecería que por cada uno hay que trabajar mucho para adjuntarlo al e-mail. Tendrías que tener quizá alguna clase a la que le pases el archivo para que te lo prepare según el tipo que sea, etc, etc. O sea, tendrías que construir tu propia biblioteca de envío de emails.

Comment: Entiendo, pero el archivo que debo mandar es en PDF, el PDF no utiliza nada exterior, sólo es el archivo.

Comment: No es cuestión de que utilice nada exterior, sino que cuando adjuntas un archivo debes tratarlo como una entidad aparte, y debes indicar a `mail` qué tipo de entidad es, indicar encabezados correctos, etc, etc. Y eso, sea PDF o cualquier archivo. Lo puedes intentar, pero sabiendo que tienes que preparar tu archivo para que `mail` sepa lo que es y lo envíe bien. Si no el cliente recibirá algo ilegible en su correo, si es que recibe algo.

Comment: He buscado algunos por intenet, y funcionan bien. El problema es que no sé cómo incorporar el código, y si esto me funciona con un dominio externo ya que no voy a utilizar gmail.

Comment: Claro María, `mail` usa por defecto el servidor desde el cual envías el mensaje, con eso no hay problema. Aunque también ese es otro punto, hay que configurar bien las cabeceras, porque de lo contrario el correo podría ser tratado como spam, sobre todo si envías varios mensajes a distintos destinatarios, tipo lista de suscripción o newsletter. Tú puedes usar gmail incluso, configurando la parte visible con los datos de tu dominio. Sería una opción interesante, valiéndote de la API de Gmail o de Google Apps Script.

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice A. Cedano no es la funcion **mail()** es muy básica, y recomendaría usar la librería PHPMailer en su lugar.

Sin embargo si requieres que sea por medio de **mail()** tu funcion debería ser:

```
function ordenEnvioCorreo(){
  $para = 'xxxxx@gmail.com, xxxxx@gmail.com,xxxxx@gmail.com, xxxxx@gmail.com'; 
  $titulo= 'Orden de compra'; 
  $mail = 'Cuerpo orden de compra';
  //crea la cadena limitadora de las partes de correo, debe ser unica
  $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
  $headers = "From: xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com"
  $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
  //se lee el archivo del servidor, se hace encode con MIME base 64 y se divide en chunks
  $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip'))); 
  /*Si se lee el archivo por medio de POST usar el siguiente codigo
  $attachment_name = "" . basename($_FILES["file_input_name"]["name"]);
  $attachment_temp = $_FILES["file_input_name"]["tmp_name"];
  if ($attachment_name != "") 
      $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment_temp))); 
  */
  ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
  ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo $mail; ?>  

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.pdf"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

  <?php 
  $message = ob_get_clean(); 

  mail( $para, $titulo, $message, $headers); 
}
```

Observa como al comenzar a definir el cuerpo del mensaje se pierde la identación, esto es necesario ya que si se agregan espacios o tabulaciones previas el correo llega como texto plano mostrando toda la definición de las partes (--PHP-mixed...), en lugar de solo "Cuerpo orden de compra".

El cuerpo de mensaje se encuentra en partes puedes identificarlas porque llevan el atributo Content-Type, cuando este es:

- **text/plain** es el cuerpo de mensaje que se mostrará
- **application/zip** es el archivo adjunto que se enviará, yo lo he dejado de esa manera y los archivos adjuntos, sean imagen, documento, zip, se entregan correctamente.

El atributo **name** en la parte del archivo adjunto debe traer la extensión del archivo que estás mandando, en tu caso comentas que será PDF.

De igual manera como comentaban el correo en el header "From:" debe ser del dominio del servidor de donde se mandaran los correos ya que de lo contrario los clientes de correo lo tomarán como suplantación de identidad y lo mandarán a Spam.

Puedes ver el ejemplo original en: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php?print=Y

Y para conocer mas de PHPMailer y su sencillez
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer