# ENVIAR RESULTADOS DE UN SELECT EN EXCEL POR MAIL PHP MYSQL

Tags: php

estoy tratando de enviar en un excel el resultado de una consulta MySql a través de la función PHP Mail(), sin tener resultados no deseo utilizar php mailer.

este es el código donde establezco la conexión a la bd y las variables con el correo a enviar:

```
$para  = 'jjj@gmail.com';
$título = 'Usuarios Registrados';
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_user";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Conexión Fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
     }
```

acá establezco el Query y el posterior envió:

```
$queryLKK = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
    $mensaje = '';  
    $mensaje = "id_user" . "\t" . 
               "usuario" . "\t"
                    ;
    $setData = '';            
          while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($resulLKK)) {  
              $rowData = '';  
              foreach ($rec as $value) {  
                  $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";  
                  $rowData .= $value;  
              }  
    $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";  
              }               
    $cabeceras  = 'Content-type: application/octet-stream' . "\r\n";  
    $cabeceras  = 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=usuarios.xls' . "\r\n";
    $cabeceras  = 'Pragma: no-cache' . "\r\n";
    $cabeceras  = 'Expires: 0' . "\r\n";    
    $mensaje = wordwrap($mensaje,70);
    $cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $cabeceras .= 'From: USER SIS<jjj@gmail.com>'. "\r\n";
    $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    mail($para, $título, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: necesito enviar el excel y no puedo... tienes alguna solución para aportar?

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error despues de llamar a mail()?

Comment: simplemente no llega nada.

Comment: ¿puedes añadir esto al código y reinitentar a ver si te sale algún error? ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: La función `mail()` de PHP es para usos muy básicos. En la documentación ellos mismos recomiendan usar otros paquetes o librerías para mensajes complejos, como son efectivamente los mensajes que llevan adjuntos ([ver esta respuesta con todos los detalles y enlaces](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116554/29967)). Así que, para tu caso deberás recurrir a PHPMailer u otro paquete.